# Triple-tap Detection on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, mobile

I'm attempting to implement a triple-tap to escape feature like that on The Trevor Project's Website. It works perfectly on laptops and desktops with a mouse. However, I'm running into problems detecting the triple-tap on mobile browsers because after the first two taps, mobile browsers register it as a double-tap and zoom in and doesn't register the triple tap. I've tried various implementations of preventDefault() and setTimeout(), but nothing seems to work. I've spent hours googling and trying different fixes, none of them work.

Before you answer, I know about disabling double-tap zoom through `touch-action: manipulation` in CSS, but that doesn't work in newer versions of Safari iOS, and I need this to support all browsers.

Here's what the code looks like, without any of the methods I've tried to fix the issue. The click part works, just not the tap version.

```
        window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            if (event.detail === 3) {
            window.location.replace("http://google.com");
            }
                });

        window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
            if (event.detail === 3) {
            window.location.replace("http://google.com");
            }
                });
```

I'm desperate, does anyone have a remedy for this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the user zoom? adding inside your head  `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0,width=device-width">`

Comment: I don't want to remove zoom entirely, just be able to register triple-clicks. I'm fine with getting rid of double-tap to zoom, but I don't want to sacrifice all zoom.

Answer (score 0):

To keep all events as they are, I suggest not using or altering them and just counting the clicks/taps and resetting if the user takes too long in the third one. The code would look like this:

```js
let numberOfClicks = 0;

//just to show in screen
const clicksText = document.getElementById("clicks");

function secondsResetClick(seconds){
  setTimeout(function(){
    numberOfClicks = 0;
  },seconds*1000)
}

//This is for click, but it would work in any listener
window.addEventListener('click', function () {
  numberOfClicks += 1;
  clicksText.textContent = numberOfClicks;
  if (numberOfClicks === 3) {
    numberOfClicks = 0;
    clicksText.textContent = 'Third Click!';
  }else if(numberOfClicks == 2){
    // Define the seconds to wait
    secondsResetClick(1);
  }
 //Just to show this example
  
});
```

```html
<span id="clicks">0</span>
```